# Debian LXC command not found

Tags: debian, installation, lxc

I am trying to do things with LXC and I have been able to manage with the `lxc-*` commands but now I have been forced to copy a file and I'm stuck because I can't get to copy the file, I have read that using `lxc file` I can do it. But at all times the message of **command not found** comes out.

I've tried googling, checking forums, trying weird stuff, etc. But none of this has worked.

I think I need to install `lxc-client` and or `lxd`, but I can't install it or even if I manage to install it, the copy command doesn't work for me. Here are some of the things I have tried:

```
apt install snapd
snap refresh
snap install snapd
snap install core

snap install lxd

apt-get install lxc-client
apt-get install lxd
```

I know there are hundreds of similar questions and almost all of them have an answer, but I can't understand what they did to make it work for them.

I also don't quite understand what difference lxc has to have to use two different types of commands, those with **lxc`-`ls** and those that use a space **lxc file**

Comment: What is your problem exactly? How are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have edited the question to make it more understandable (I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was simpler than I thought, I just had to restart the computer and the commands worked, looking for a little more information I found that `snap refresh` did the job of reloading them. Here is the list of commands that I have used:

```
apt install snapd -y
snap refresh
snap install core
snap install lxd
snap refresh
```

I still don't really understand the difference between these and the others. I have not discovered how the command `lxc file` works, which was my interest, but little by little and question by question

Comment: It did not help me at all, I had to copy the files as indicated [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1070454/648392)

Answer (score 1):

Well LXC and LXD are two different software pieces :)
Both of them are based on Linux Kernel Containers. LXC was first, it is very basic in terms of features and administration but does the job well if you want to just have another version of Ubuntu or Debian and not really extensively manipulate with containers themselves.
LXD is (AFAIK) a Canonical product that is using the same Linux Containers but is waaaay more developed, has reach functionalities, and is dedicated to intensive containers using a-la Docker or up to virtual hosting, etc. Unfortunately, LXD command-line tool is called `lxc` (bastards), which is why there is such a level of confusion.

Comment: +1 for trying to clear up the mess.  Conclusion: Use 'lxc ' and ignore anything that makes use of 'lxc-'