# lxc send file or copy

Tags: bash, lxd

I am trying to copy a file with lxc, now I am already desperate. Here are some commands that I have tried:

```
#temp=$(cat 2.sh)
#lxc-attach -n containerName echo $temp > /root/2.sh
#lxc-attach -n containerName cat /root/2.sh
->

#temp=$(cat 2.sh)
#lxc-attach -n containerName -- bash -c 'echo $temp > /root/2.sh'
#lxc-attach -n containerName cat /root/2.sh
->

#lxc-attach -n containerName -- bash -c 'echo $(cat 2.sh) > /root/2.sh'
->cat: 2.sh: No such file or directory

#lxc-attach -n containerName -- bash -c 'echo "$(cat 2.sh)" > /root/2.sh'
->cat: 2.sh: No such file or directory


#lxc file push 2.sh containerName/root/
->Error: not found
```

*The `->` is the output*

Containers are built with `lxc-` and do not appear in the `lxc list` list, but in the `lxc-ls` list.

**Any help is welcome**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution only works in the case that the LXC is in a machine in which you can connect with SSH, **DOES NOT WORK WITH VIRTULIZED LXC**. You need access to the lxc folders!

`cp /root/input/2.sh /var/lib/lxc/NAME_LXC/rootfs/root/2.sh`

The truth is that it is a mess for me to understand LXC/LXD. Now I understand many things and it became clearer to me how it works from behind

The trick is that everything is based on physical files in this path `/var/lib/lxc/`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cat 2.sh | lxc-attach -n containerName tee /root/2.sh
```

Note:

I tested this with docker containers, as I don't have lxc available at the moment. With docker this works when the `-i` parameter for an interactive session is specified. I don't see a corresponding parameter for `lxc-attach`, I don't know if this is necessary or possible.

Comment: Well, the truth is that no, if they don't have the format indicated above directly, they don't work. But +1 for teaching me how to do that in docker. I leave an example `cat 2.sh | docker exec -i name_container tee /root/2.sh`